# Illegal string offset 'id' on index and header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a big time newbie and I couldn't figure out how to change this description on my own. My knowledge on php is very limited - a very detailed response would be kindly appreciated!

I'm getting these warnings on our site:

```
Illegal string offset 'id' in /home3/seando12/public_html/hgbjj.com/wp-content/themes/academica/index.php on line 4

Illegal string offset 'id' in /home3/seando12/public_html/hgbjj.com/wp-content/themes/academica/header.php on line 4
```

**Index.php: line 4**

```
 <?php 
 global $options;
 foreach ($options as $value) {
 if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
```

**Header.php - line 4**

```
 <?php 
 global $options; 
 foreach ($options as $value) {
 if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }`
```

Comment: I see variable variables `$$value['id']` vs `$value['id']`. Is that your intention?

Comment: I didn't write this myself, it's off a theme on wp. So I'm not sue what the intention was...

Comment: Well, the error indicates that the `'id'` is not defined as an array key.  The question is, which of the many `'id'`'s that are on that line that is doing it.  The `$$value['id']` _seems_ suspect.  But it may not be the issue.  Try doing a `var_dump($options)` before that `foreach` loop to see what kind of data is in it.

Comment: I've been doing a little more research, the issue started since the upgrade to php 5.5 - I think the theme i'm using might not be up to date. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by calling my hosting company, they reverted my site to php 3.4 , which fixed the issue. Thank you anyway for trying to help! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

After PHP version 5.4 (I think), they changed the the way PHP responds to these errors. Basically the message is telling you that PHP was expecting an array with a key and then a value.

I reckon our issue sits with our `$$value['id']` which should change to `$value['id']`. The double dollar symbol is probably registering weirdly as a 2 tiered array, which is probably the cause of the error here.